# What's wrong with authentication?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, settings

I'm trying to change sqlite3 to postgresql in django and getting this error:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "mat"

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'ohhbjebb',
        'USER' : '',
        'PASSWORD' : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'HOST' : 'balarama.db.elephantsql.com',
        'PORT' : '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the `USER` empty ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a valid user of postgresql who have the access of this data base . and you need to define the username as shown below

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'ohhbjebb',
    'USER' : 'your database username who had the access of this database',
    'PASSWORD' : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'HOST' : 'balarama.db.elephantsql.com',
    'PORT' : '5432',
}
```

}

if you don't define any User connection will assume your os user as db user

error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "mat"

here "mat" must be you os user name .